# How to check for the presence of no value in a "params[:attribute]"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

When I have a an array like this:

```
[5] pry(#<HomeController>)> params["search"]["sources"] => [""]
```

How do I check that instance to be true?

I tried the following, but it fails:

```
[8] pry(#<HomeController>)> params[:search][:sources].empty?
=> false
[9] pry(#<HomeController>)> params[:search][:sources].nil?
=> false
[3] pry(#<HomeController>)> params["search"]["sources"].empty?
=> false
[4] pry(#<HomeController>)> params["search"]["sources"].eql? ""
=> false
[10] pry(#<HomeController>)> params[:search][:sources].blank?
=> false
[11] pry(#<HomeController>)> params[:search][:sources].any?
=> true
```

Whenever the value of an attribute of my `params` is empty, or equal to `""`, I want to do something specific.

I would like it to be the conditional of an `if` statement, so it has to return true in the above case.

Here is the actual full `params` I am checking:

```
 params
=> <ActionController::Parameters {"search"=><ActionController::Parameters {"keywords"=>"", "types"=>[""], "categories"=>["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "Hockey", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""], "date_from"=>"", "date_to"=>"", "sources"=>[""], "genders"=>[""], "ages"=>[""]} permitted: false>, "controller"=>"home", "action"=>"index"} permitted: false>
```

Basically I want to check to see if any of the values in `params[:search][:categories]` is not empty. In the above case, we see that one of the values is equal to the string `Hockey`, so in this case it should return false.

Comment: Please don't use tags like "Edit 1". Instead incorporate the addition into the question as if it'd been there all along. We can tell what changed if we need to know. "[Should “Edit:” in edits be discouraged?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255644/128421)"
helps explain. Also, `params["search"]["sources"] => [""]` is not an array, it's an object dump. Instead, we need the actual Ruby code that would define the array and assign it to `params`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably try to avoid having to check for both – a blank array or an array including only an empty string. But if I had to I would to it explicit:

```
array = params[:search][:sources]
array.blank? || array == ['']
```

Another option might be:

```
params[:search][:sources].first.blank?
```

But I think the second option is harder to understand (at least all cases in which it would return `true`).

For the `categories` the condition would be:

```
params[:search][:categories].any?(&:present?)
```

Comment: So `array.blank?` doesn't work, but `.first.blank?` does.....as does `== ['']`. So if you modify the first part of the answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Actually...I am going to update the question and show you the entire params I am trying to check.

Comment: @marcamillion. I think you need both. `array.blank?` return `true` when the array is empty (`[]`) and `array == ['']` returns `true` when the array includes only an empty string (`[""]`). I understand your question that you want to cover both cases. Whereas the second option would return `true` for both cases (`[]` and `[""]`).

Comment: Oh that's a very good point. You are right in this instance. How do I handle the updated condition, which is what I was really trying to achieve? Refresh the question to see the edit.

Comment: @marcamillion I updated my answer to address your updated question.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks much!

Answer (score 0):

```
params[:search][:sources].all?(&:blank?)
```

Comment: Rather than toss out code please explain why it is the solution. We want to educate, not just solve the immediate question.